# libsndfile and Photoshop plugin development issue

Tags: c++, plugins, dll, photoshop, libsndfile

i'm trying to compile a **64 bits** version of my **32 bits** plugin which works ok on **CS2**

i came to a point where when i add in my code any **libsndfile** related function (**sf_open**, **sfinfo**, **sf_read_double**) the plugin don't show anymore on the plugin list.

If i remove them, the plugin shows back.

So how come ?

I've tried to put a **boolean** before the code to false, and modify to **true** when the function is used but it doesn't work. The only thing that works, is when i put **"if (false) {}"** between the functions.

I don't understand how **Photoshop** works: Is it testing the plugin in some ways ? If so, the code part where i put a **boolean** to **false**, should not work, though should make the plugin appear...

please enlighten me.

Jeff

Answer (score 0):

okay i found out that putting libsndfile-1.dll in the system32 folder makes the plugin shows again. Only issue : i don't want to put the file in the system32 folder, but rather the plugin folder's. But the plugin doesn't show if i put the file only in the plugin folder...

So how to deal with that?

thanks

Jeff